# DataTables iniating multiple child tables with columnDefs intact

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

**Background**: I have 7 DataTables being created by a PHP loop (HTML is created directly on the page - not sourced from AJAX or anywhere else). Within these summary level DataTables, I have a further 6 detail level DataTables in a nested loop (one for each of the summary level tables - apart from one). These are in the last column of each summary table and using the `responsive` option I am able to have the content of the detail tables pushed to a child row as per https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

**Problem:** I am trying to initiate each child (detail) table in the `initComplete: function(){}` of the parent  table. It seems to be doing something although the table doesn't retain any of the DataTables libraries functionality (column definition widths for example).

My main issue is that is ignoring my DataTable options (setting widths via `columnDefs` in this case is vital:

Am I missing something? Is there a reason it's choosing to override/ignore my column widths. The parent table allows `responsive` and `columnDefs`.

See snippet for example:

```js
$('#summary_table').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  autoWidth: false,
  searching: false,
  columnDefs: [{
      'width': '3%',
      'targets': [0]
    },
    {
      'width': '10%',
      'targets': [1, 2]
    },
    {
      "className": "dt-center",
      "targets": "_all"
    },

  ],
  initComplete: function() {
    console.log("Initialisation of table complete");
    var sub_table = $('#summary_table').find('.ic-detail-table');
    if (sub_table.length > 0) {
      var sub_table_inst = $(sub_table).DataTable({
        paging: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        searching: false,
        columnDefs: [
          //IGNORED????
          {
            'width': '10%',
            'targets': [0]
          },
          {
            'width': '25%',
            'targets': [1]
          },
          {
            'width': '25%',
            'targets': [2]
          },
          {
            'width': '40%',
            'targets': [3]
          },
          {
            "className": "dt-center",
            "targets": "_all"
          },
        ],
        ordering: true,
        sorting: true,
        initComplete: function() {
          console.log("SUB TABLE INIT COMPLETE");
        },
        responsive: true,
        dom: '<"clear">rt',
        order: [
          [1, 'asc']
        ]
      });
    }
  },
  ordering: false,
  responsive: true,
  dom: '<"clear">rt',

  order: [
    [1, 'asc']
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.4/r-2.2.2/sl-1.2.6/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.4/r-2.2.2/sl-1.2.6/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class='table table-bordered display compact' id='summary_table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Heading one</th>
      <th>Heading two</th>
      <th>Heading three</th>
      <th class='none'>Detail table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>cell one</td>
      <td>cell two</td>
      <td>cell three</td>
      <td>
        <table class='table compact' class='ic-detail-table'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Heading one</th>
              <th>Heading two</th>
              <th>Heading three</th>
              <th>Heading four</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Heading one</td>
              <td>Heading two</td>
              <td>Heading three</td>
              <td>Heading four</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the default behavior of [child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html]). Please follow [this link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42045/nested-tables) to learn more and try to overcome this issue

Comment: Ideally I would rather not use the function to create child rows dynamically in java script. The Html already exists, can I not just initialise datatables on it so It recognises the options given?

Comment: You can't. Datatables doesn't have this kind of option available. But in any case how would you want to do it? Knowing that your outter table got 3 columns and your inner one got 4?

Comment: I don't want the tables to be in line with the outer table. I just want to be able to create more uniform widths for my columns (but still allow responsiveness). The inner table isn't a continuation of the outer table, it's just showing more detailed content so doesn't need the same headings etc. What I'm getting at the moment is small columns where there is not much content and over-sized columns where the width isn't restricted so it just looks odd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do isn't by default part of datatables, but you can hack your way through it by adding a maximum for width for the classes `dtr-details` and `compact`

```js
$('#summary_table').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  autoWidth: false,
  searching: false,
  columnDefs: [{
      'width': '3%',
      'targets': [0]
    },
    {
      'width': '10%',
      'targets': [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      "className": "dt-center",
      "targets": "_all"
    },

  ],
  initComplete: function() {
    console.log("Initialisation of table complete");
    var sub_table = $('#summary_table').find('.ic-detail-table');
    if (sub_table.length > 0) {
      var sub_table_inst = $(sub_table).DataTable();
    }
  },
  ordering: false,
  responsive: true,
  dom: '<"clear">rt',

  order: [
    [1, 'asc']
  ]
});
```

```css
.dtr-details,
.compact {
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.4/r-2.2.2/sl-1.2.6/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.4/r-2.2.2/sl-1.2.6/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class='table table-bordered display compact' id='summary_table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Heading one</th>
      <th>Heading two</th>
      <th>Heading three</th>
      <th class='none'>Detail table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>cell one</td>
      <td>cell two</td>
      <td>cell three</td>
      <td>
        <table class='table compact' class='ic-detail-table'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Heading one</th>
              <th>Heading two</th>
              <th>Heading three</th>
              <th>Heading four</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Heading one</td>
              <td>Heading two</td>
              <td>Heading three</td>
              <td>Heading four</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also note that I changed your `'targets': [1, 2]` to `'targets': [1, 2, 3]` and you don't need any options in the child datatables, as they won't be taken into account.

If you add an id to the inner table, for example `innerTable` you could then just add this css to make the first column's width 3% :

```
#innerTable thead tr th:first-child,
#innerTable tbody tr td:first-child {
  width: 3%!important;
}
```

```js
$('#summary_table').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  autoWidth: false,
  searching: false,
  columnDefs: [{
      'width': '3%',
      'targets': [0]
    },
    {
      'width': '10%',
      'targets': [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      "className": "dt-left",
      "targets": "_all"
    },

  ],
  initComplete: function() {
    console.log("Initialisation of table complete");
    var sub_table = $('#summary_table').find('.ic-detail-table');
    if (sub_table.length > 0) {
      var sub_table_inst = $(sub_table).DataTable();
    }
  },
  ordering: false,
  responsive: true,
  dom: '<"clear">rt',

  order: [
    [1, 'asc']
  ]
});
```

```css
.dtr-details,
.compact {
  width: 100% !important;
}

#innerTable thead tr th:first-child,
#innerTable tbody tr td:first-child {
  width: 3% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.4/r-2.2.2/sl-1.2.6/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.4/r-2.2.2/sl-1.2.6/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class='table table-bordered display compact' id='summary_table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Heading one</th>
      <th>Heading two</th>
      <th>Heading three</th>
      <th class='none'>Detail table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>cell one</td>
      <td>cell two</td>
      <td>cell three</td>
      <td>
        <table id="innerTable" class='table compact' class='ic-detail-table'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Heading two</th>
              <th>Heading three</th>
              <th>Heading four</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Heading two</td>
              <td>Heading three</td>
              <td>Heading four</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Heading two</td>
              <td>Heading three</td>
              <td>Heading four</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>Heading two</td>
              <td>Heading three</td>
              <td>Heading four</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6fp3kbnh/

Comment: This has made all the columns equally sized on the detail row right? What if I want to define the sizes of each column? I suppose I could do :nth()?

In my actual version of this the first column is just and ID so only needs say 3% of the table width, I then have some text columns that need maybe 20% each and then some data columns with percentages in that need say 10% each. But this needs to happen across all of the detail tables so they look uniform.

Comment: Why don't you add a specific id to the child table? It'll simplify a lot of things @MrDansk

Comment: In my example it doesn't have an ID. In the real version they do have ID's but they are dynamically created via PHP outputting the HTML. What would you suggest if I had an ID on the table.

Comment: @MrDansk I would suggest my post edit, please check it

Comment: Just checked it, sorry! That could work! I'll have to apply it to my actual code on Monday to test, but thanks for your help. I will accept the answer if it works out.

Comment: I'll be waiting to hear from you.